# Position column text in absolute points itext sharp

Tags: c#, itext

i working with itext sharp to create PDF on the fly. I am using ColumnText because i am dealing with Right-To-Left content. By searching the web, i understand that column.SetSimpleColumn is accept 4 args (x,y,w,h) right? My first problem is that i don't know the width and height of the column, i need that it will be dynamic by the text content. Any one have an idea how to set the column width and height according to his content inside?

```
try
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < project.Slides[i].Labels.Count; j++)
            {
                string pageContext = project.Slides[i].Labels[j].Text;
                int fontNumber = Convert.ToInt32(project.Slides[i].Labels[j].Font);
                int fontSize = Convert.ToInt32(project.Slides[i].Labels[j].Size);
                float fontSizePoints = (float)fontSize * (float)2.3;
                string fontColor = project.Slides[i].Labels[j].Color;
                float fontX = (float)project.Slides[i].Labels[j].X;
                float fontY = (float)project.Slides[i].Labels[j].Y;
                var color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(fontColor);

                baseFont = GetBaseFont(fontNumber);

                float w = baseFont.GetWidthPoint(pageContext, fontSizePoints);
                Font dFont = new Font(baseFont, fontSizePoints);


                dFont.Color = new BaseColor(color);
                ColumnText column = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
                column.SetSimpleColumn(fontX, fontY, w, 100);

                column.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
                column.AddElement(new Paragraph(pageContext, dFont));

                column.Go();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
```

I am attach image to describe the issue. There can be one or 20 textcolumn in document. i dont know what the size of the font and how long are this text. it can be 2 words or 30 words. the only info i have is the x,y of the left | bottom coords (and the font family, size, color...) My question was how to create TextColumn (need to use this because of RTL support) and place it by specific coords position.
[image]

Comment: I was trying to use float w = baseFont.GetWidthPoint(pageContext, fontSizePoints); but its not give me the correct width. the context is breaking

Comment: I would upgrade to iText 7 and use pdfCalligraph. That way, you'll avoid problems like this. As I already wrote in answer to previous questions posted by you, support for Right-To-Left in versions prior to iText 7 is rather limited, and iText 5 is in maintenance mode which means that we don't do active development on iText 5 anymore. There is no out-of-the-box support for what you need in iText 5, so either you'll have to extend iText 5 yourself, or switch to iText 7.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie i know you are the best hope for itextsharp solutions and that you know this library more than anyone else, please, this is the last issue i have for this project. all project was build using itext 5, it will be hell to override all project code now.there must be some way to accomplish this issue

Comment: You can always do multiple test runs with `ColumnText` and query the result to find out good dimensions. Nonetheless,  this will mean some programming. That been said, you should know the column width and top left or top right location, shouldn't you?

Comment: @mkl that was the original question. How to get the correct width of the ColumnText after the content is insert. The float w = baseFont.GetWidthPoint(pageContext, fontSizePoints) is not working well.

Comment: Since you're almost ready to go to production (except for this problem), maybe it's time to get a commercial license and a support contract to get this solved. You will probably need a commercial license anyway, because you can only use iTextSharp for free if you obey the rules of the AGPL. Are you aware of those rules? What is the context of your application?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie , I am using this community (StackOverflow) for years and this is the first time i am meeting someone like you. In my searching for solutions iv'e seen a lot of answers from you to other users. and the only 2 answers you have is 1. Upgrade to iText7 OR 2. Read my book. I dont think you need to answer programmers who looking for solutions if you dont want / know how to help them. I decided to migrate to PdfSharp. Thanks

Comment: I have a 50K+ reputation, so I have been on Stack Overflow for a while too. When confronted with people like you, I often use the expression "Givers have to set limits, but takers rarely do." The fact that you are on Stack Overflow for years, but still haven't got a reputation > 100, and the fact that you are looking for a solution without willing to pay, tells me that you are a taker who doesn't give anything back. Is that how you see this community? As a place where you can get things for free without ever having to contribute anything back?

Comment: @Elidotnet *that was the original question. How to get the correct width of the ColumnText after the content is insert.* - but that already is the wrong question. Before even starting to add content to the `ColumnText`, you should have an idea where you want its content to go. Thus, you should have the width. If there is a reason for this not to be the case, you should explain the exact situation.

Comment: @mkl Thank you very much for patience. I was starting to rebuild my project in other library but i will post this update cause from what i see in the web, no one has a idea how to work this out. Thanks

Comment: @Elidotnet Concerning your edit: It sounds a bit like each `ColumnText` instance is used to draw a single line only. Is that correct?

Comment: @mkl correct. only one line of text (no option to had multiline text)

Comment: @Elidotnet In that case, have you tried using the static helper method `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned`? There is an overload with an `arabicOptions` parameter. I've not yet had to work with RTL scripts, so I cannot tell from experience, but for LTR scripts this helper method usually provides all the functionality you need to draw a text line anywhere anchored at the left, the center, or the right.

Comment: @mkl Thank you very much for patience and support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mkl thanks for reply. The best solution i found is that. working great with absolute position + RTL support.

```
try
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < project.Slides[i].Labels.Count; j++)
            {
                string pageContext = project.Slides[i].Labels[j].Text;
                int fontNumber = Convert.ToInt32(project.Slides[i].Labels[j].Font);
                int fontSize = Convert.ToInt32(project.Slides[i].Labels[j].Size);
                float fontSizePoints = (float)fontSize * (float)2.1;
                string fontColor = project.Slides[i].Labels[j].Color;

                float X = (float)project.Slides[i].Labels[j].X;
                float Y = pHeightPoints - (float)project.Slides[i].Labels[j].Y;
                float width = (float)project.Slides[i].Labels[j].Widht;
                float height = (float)project.Slides[i].Labels[j].Heigh;

                float llx = X;
                float lly = Y + height;
                float urx = X + width;
                float ury = Y;

                var color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(fontColor);

                baseFont = GetBaseFont(fontNumber);
                float w = baseFont.GetWidthPoint(pageContext, fontSizePoints);
                Font dFont = new Font(baseFont, fontSizePoints);
                dFont.Color = new BaseColor(color);

                PlaceText(writer.DirectContent, pageContext, 
                    new Font(baseFont, fontSizePoints, 
                        Font.NORMAL,
                        new BaseColor(color)), llx, lly, urx, ury, 14, 
                        Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
```

and...

```
protected static void PlaceText(PdfContentByte pdfContentByte
                            , string text
                            , iTextSharp.text.Font font
                            , float lowerLeftx
                            , float lowerLefty
                            , float upperRightx
                            , float upperRighty
                            , float leading
                            , int alignment)
{
    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(pdfContentByte);
    ct.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
    ct.SetSimpleColumn(new Phrase(text, font), lowerLeftx, lowerLefty, upperRightx, upperRighty, leading, alignment);
    ct.Go();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The float w = baseFont.GetWidthPoint(pageContext, fontSizePoints); is not in use